# How to paste multiple Bash commands into a shell without losing some?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, shell

It's nice to copy-paste a series of Bash commands that you find on a website. But depending on the commands, sometimes you lose a few. Maybe they get swallowed up by programs that read from standard input, or perhaps there's another explanation.

So I end up doing this sometimes:

```
$ bash <<EOF
cmd2
...
EOF
```

Is there a better way? Some Bash option? An SSH option? (My setup is an Bash running on an Ubuntu server, which I'm SSH'ed to from a standard OS X terminal. Not sure how much of that is relevant.)

EDIT

### Example

In response to requests for a concrete example, here's one. I pasted the following four lines into an SSH shell (from my Snow Leopard desktop) connected to a stock Ubuntu Quantal running on an OpenStack VM, in the Bash shell.

```
sudo apt-get install -y r-base gdebi-core
sudo apt-get install -y libapparmor1 # Required only for Ubuntu, not Debian
wget http://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-0.97.314-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-0.97.314-amd64.deb
```

The first two commands executed (successfully), while the last two were apparently never received by the server (or at least, never processed by Bash).

Comment: Do you have a specific example of what fails?

Comment: No. Usually a long-running command, like `apt-get update`, `git clone`, `wget` etc.

Comment: Without a concrete problem description it's going to be hard to diagnose what the real issue is. I have yet to see Bash "losing" commands out of nowhere. (I also run OS X and work a lot on remote Linux machines.)

Comment: Problem: need a convenient, robust mechanism for pasting a series of commands into a shell then executing them, that doesn't rely on the vagaries of the terminal itself.

Comment: What I meant by a concrete problem description was, for example, "I have *this* snippet I copy and paste, and *this* is what gets executed, while *this* is what is lost". Do you usually lose all commands after a certain one, or just some in between, etc?

Comment: you could always paste the commands into a new txt file and then execute as a script?

Comment: slhck: I know what you're asking for. I don't have it, and I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: James: yes, but that's even clumsier than the method I originally posted.

Comment: OT here, but interesting nevertheless. At least I was really surprised, that you sometimes don't get what you expect with copy&paste from websites: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Old-tricks-are-new-again-Dangerous-copy-paste-1842898.html

Comment: This reads like game of "Find me a rock"("No, that one's too big."; "No, that one's too small."; "Not that one, I don't like the color.")  A more explicit problem description might get you fewer guesses and some more relevant answers you'd like better.

Comment: @JRobert: it's more like "Find me a blue rock that weighs about the same as a cat", "No, that one is red.", "No, that weighs much more than a cat". Maybe it's a hard game, and maybe the rules aren't totally clear, but those guesses are *clearly* wrong. \ Also, you don't have to play :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591591/linux-paste-commands-into-terminal-and-have-them-run-one-after-the-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution is to run this:

```
bash -c '<paste commands here>'
```

This works even if the paste contains newline characters. It may fail if the paste contains single quotes. If you're aware of [the bash quoting rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html), you should be able to modify this method for the specific commands that you're trying to run.

Comment: That's excellent - I had no idea you could put newlines in command lines.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use something like `pbpaste | bash`. And `edit-and-execute-command` (`\C-x\C-e`) also works with multiple commands.

If some commands require root permissions, you can use `sudo -v` to validate the timestamp for 5 minutes.

Comment: The OP is SSHing into an Ubuntu server, so `pbpaste`ing into `bash` is not easily doable there.

Comment: Ah, that edit-current-line trick works. (Ctrl-x, Ctrl-E or ^X^E in other notation).

Comment: It is quite a few keystrokes all up.: Ctrl+X, Ctrl+E, Cmd-V, Ctrl+X, Y, <enter>

Comment: `xsel` on Linux.

Comment: @SteveBennett looks like your $VISUAL editor is nano ;) the keystrokes are different for other editors

Comment: Heh, apparently it was back in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I make such cuts and pastes into my favourite text editor, named appropriately, where I can then carefully look for extraneous characters, and ensure that I'll be running what I expect to be running.  I'm strongly adverse to cutting and pasting code snippets into an interactive shell:  who knows what extra commands might be picked up by the cut & paste operation?

Once your text file has the verified commands saved, they can then be executed with the built-in command

`source <filename>`

Comment: Ok, and once you've satisfied yourself that the contents of the clipboard is precisely what you want to run?

Comment: Original updated; On the saved file, use 'source <filename>' to execute the statements within, without having to make it executable.

Comment: And now you have a script file lying around which you'll never run again. That's pretty clumsy.

Comment: then you delete it and it won't be around anymore.

Comment: Yep. Way clumsier than the original <<EOF method.